# SPNEGO get user details

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, kerberos, spnego

I have setup the spnego library in tomcat using the JNDIRealm.
Followed following guide : https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-configuring-tomcat-single-sign-on-w
I would like to know I have could get the users group from LDAP in another java class I am using to create a user in my database. I would like to get all user details like email, phone etc.. as well as all the groups the user is part of.

Comment: Just to be clear, you did manage to connect to LDAP within a java class ? If yes, can you add your code snippet ?

Comment: I just followed the link and it does autheticate user and gives me user name. I however now want to write code to get more details of user. To get user name I use request.getRemoteUser().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this list](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) to get all the attributes you can retrieve from LDAP.

---

For example, let's say you want the Name, Group, Job Title, Phone Number and E-mail of your users. (For consistancy with your question, I'll use the same "dummy value" as your link).

The first step is to connect to LDAP in your Java class, for that I rather use a separate function :

```
public static Hashtable<String, String> getContextEnv() {
  Hashtable<String, String> contextEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
  contextEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
  contextEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://dc.mydomain.com:3268");
  contextEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
  contextEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=TECHNICAL_USER,DC=mydomain,DC=com");
  contextEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "TECHNICAL_USER_PASSWORD");
  contextEnv.put("java.naming.referral", "follow");
  contextEnv.put("java.naming.ldap.derefAliases", "never");
  contextEnv.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
  contextEnv.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "60000");

  return contextEnv;
}
```

Where **TECHNICAL_USER** is the one you use to create your keytab with the *ktpass* command.

---

Next step is to call that function, and create a **SearchControls** object. This is where you will put the attribute you want to get (see the link above for all the possibilities) and some paramaters (timeout for example) :

```
Hashtable<String, String> contextEnv = getContextEnv();

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(contextEnv);    

// UserID - Last Name - First Name - Group - Job Title - Phone Number - Email address
String[] attrIDs = { "sAMAccountName", "sn", "givenName", "memberOf", "title", "telephoneNumber", "mail"};
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
searchControls.setTimeLimit(6000);
```

---

Final step, you get the info of your current user where **currentUser** is the UserID your corporation use to identify the employees :

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = ctx.search("DC=mydomain,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=" + currentUser + ")", searchControls);

if (searchResults.hasMore()) {
  SearchResult currentSearchResult = searchResults.next();
  Attributes searchResultAttributes = currentSearchResult.getAttributes();

  String userID = searchResultAttributes.get("sAMAccountName");
  String lastName = searchResultAttributes.get("sn");
  String firstName = searchResultAttributes.get("givenName");
  String group = searchResultAttributes.get("memberOf");
  String jobTitle = searchResultAttributes.get("title");
  String phoneNumber = searchResultAttributes.get("telephoneNumber");
  String email = searchResultAttributes.get("mail");

  searchResults.close();
}

ctx.close();
```